# Initializing Chart Js Multiple times for and Array of Objects

Tags: angularjs, chart.js

As the title suggests  here is a snippet of my code

```
angular.forEach($scope.students,function(){

  var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
  var myRadarChart = new Chart(ctx).Radar(chartData);
  //Data//
  var subjects = [];
  var scores = [];

  angular.forEach(myData.subjects, function(subject){
    subjects.push(myData.subject.name);
  });

  angular.forEach($scope.data.subjects, function(score){
    scores.push(score.grades.assignments+score.grades.tests+score.grades.final);
  });

  var chartData = {
    labels : subjects,
    datasets : [
        {
        data: scores,
        fillColor: color2,
        strokeColor: color1,
        pointColor: color1,
        pointStrokeColor: color1,
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)"
      }
    ]
  };

  });


}]);
```

I have everything else working but Im not sure how to properly initialize each chart uniquely for each object in data.json , have a [look](http://plnkr.co/edit/RXzjPllg0RSWjvgMjIoU?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a directive and it looks like there's [already one out there](https://github.com/carlcraig/tc-angular-chartjs) for chart.js and AngularJS.  This way you can easily set up the data for each chart.